# Make hands and shoulders fat and reduce belly fat at a time

Tags: bellyfat

Basically My **hands and shoulders** looks **thin** and I have **lot more belly** fat.

I want to make my hands and shoulders fat and want to reduce belly.

Usually i eat **2/3 times rice** in a day , less amount of **fruits** and 100 gm of **chicken** per week . I dont drink **milk** . and almost no **junk foods**  no **chocolates** and **sweets.** But i eat curd a lot in a day.

I dont do any **workout, running** but 90 minutes **walk** per day

i am **26** years old with **6.1** tall , about **171 punds/78 kg**.

Please give me some suggestions what procedures i need to follow to reduce my belly fat ?

Comment: @SeanDuggan Thanks for comment, I saw that question..... but my question is to increase fat on hands and shoulders on same time.....

Comment: {nods} But unfortunately, the answer is much the same. You can't target fat loss. You can't target fat gain. You can do exercises to increase muscle mass in your shoulders , but the hands don't really have much to work with.

Comment: "100 gm of chicken **per week**"?? You're underweight, and eating far too little protein.  Consider a strength-training program and a more protein-heavy diet.

Comment: @CCCV Thanks , so i  need to take more proteins and cut all carbohydrates [ in other words `eat food with low calories with high energy and avoid food with high calories`] ?

Comment: Yes, eat more protein.  No, don't cut all carbohydrates (or all fats, either).  You need some amounts of each on a daily basis -- I don't know exact amounts; those depend on your body and activities, etc.  You will need even more of all of those macronutrients if you attempt to get stronger and bigger, which I suggest that you do.  You can lose bodyfat more easily once you've built more lean bodymass (that is, muscle and bone).

Comment: http://examine.com/nutrition/how-much-protein-do-i-need-every-day/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not possible to reduce fat in only certain parts of the body**. When you lose weight your body takes fat from everywhere on the body. The only way to actually lose weight is to stay in a caloric deficit, so either eat less or increase the amount of physical activity you do. I personally use an app to keep track of my calories - something you should try too.

Also if you wish to get bigger shoulders I would recommend working out as it will help you lose weight and build muscle simultaneously (if you have not done much physical training before).

Comment: i was worried if i do physical activites, along with my stomach, i will lose little bit fat in hands and shoulders also.... thanks for suggestions, i will try.....

Comment: adding weight training, if you have the time, can beneficial.